# Playing Audio file depending on position of image which is moving using Accelerometer

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Im trying to make a Project of car moving on road

I wanted to give a warning signal if my car crosses the lane on road
how to know the position of car and play audio if the car is on other lane.

Its kind of urgent to me

Thanks

Comment: Is this app supposed to detect the location of a real car?

Comment: Don't you know the location of your own object? If so then I assume that the problem is in knowing how to play a sound.

Comment: Please let us know what you've tried. This is not the place to ask for an application to be written for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to play a sound:

```
-(void)playSomeSound
{
    NSURL *soundFilePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    AVAudioPlayer *sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFilePath error:nil];
    [sound play];
    [sound release];
}
```

Just call [self playSomeSound] whenever your car crosses the lane. Other formats of sound work too, but not all do, so be careful.